# enable root log-in in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: permissions, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

How do I enable root login to an Ubuntu Server 12.04?

That is, to be able to ssh as root. I can only login now as a regular user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set a root password (sudo su passwd)
Depending how your ssh is installed, you usually need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change "PermitRootLogin no" to  "PermitRootLogin yes"

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add the following line:

PermitRootLogin yes

Comment: the "PermitRootLogin" line exists already by default, rather than add a conflicting statement better to change the line that says PermitRootLogin no

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't allow direct SSH login as root. It's a pretty major security risk. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-deny-or-restrict-access-to-users-and-groups.html

Why not log in as a user with sudo privileges then do 'sudo bash' or 'sudo sh'
This site explains a bit more: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57040/what-is-the-difference-between-su-sudo-bash-and-sudo-sh

If you really must enable ssh as root the first link should give you the info you need to configure OpenSSH assuming that's the server you're using.
You'll have to set a root password too, this site should help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling%20the%20root%20account